# need help converting string input to multiple variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = str(input())
y = meh
z = yee
print(x)
```

how do I make it so that I can input `' y, z'` and make it so that it prints `' meh yee '`? trying to make a simple encrypting thingy and would appreciate some help :)

Comment: You could use a dictionary: `encoder_ring = {'y': 'meh', 'z': 'yee'}` to associate letters to nonsense words.

Answer (score 0):

One big change would be to change from storing the `y = meh` relationship in variables to storing it in a dictionary.

Here's a way to use regular expressions to replace the words in your input.  I've made some assumptions about what you want to do with commas and words you don't have a rule for.

```
import re

replacements = {
    'y': 'meh',
    'z': 'yee'
}

def replace_word(match):
    return replacements.get(match.group(1), match.group(0))

s = input()

print(re.sub(r'\b(\w+)\b,?', replace_word, s))
```

This changes `"    x, y, z    "` to `"    x, meh yee    "`

Answer (score -1):

Evaluate your string before printing it. But note that this is **DANGEROUS** if you intend to let the (untrusted) user choose what to put in `x` as it can then execute arbitrary code on the machine. As suggested by @bruno desthuilliers, [this article explains why](http://%20nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

```
x = str(input())
y = 'meh'
z = 'yee'
print(eval(x))
```

outputs

```
('meh', 'yee')
```

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't see your warning and immediatly pulled out the gun when seeing `eval` indeed - so please accept my apologies ;)

Comment: As to why `eval` is dangerous: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: better safe than sorry ;)

Comment: nb: if you edit your post (you could for example add the above link ;-)) I'll happily retract my downvote (which I can't ATM - thx SO).